# Shake effect on text syntax in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to give shake effect on my input type text when validation fails. It is giving shake effect but I don't know how to change default value of direction, distance and times. Also I think I'm doing something wrong in storing value of textbox in variable a. Please tell me the correct syntax. Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#submitBtn").click(function(){
                    $a = $("#userNameTxt").value;
                    if ($a != "text")
                    {
                        $("#userNameTxt").effect("shake");
                    }
                });
            });

        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="#" >
        <input type="text" name="userNameTxt" id="userNameTxt" placeholder="username" />
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submitBtn" />
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Always go for the API documentation before posting here..you will get all the details there itself..

Comment: Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/N2nKw/1/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some thing  like these options ??

```
 $("#button").click(function(){
         $(".target").effect( "shake", 
          {times:4}, 1000 );
      });
```

Here is [shake effect fully explained](http://creativedev.in/2013/01/jquery-shake-effect-explained/)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
$("#userNameTxt").effect('shake', { 
times: 10,
duration: 1000,
direction: 'left' // 'right' for right
});
```